# Is int *a[5] an array of 5 pointers or a pointer pointing to an array of size 5?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int *a[5];
```

Is this an array of 5 pointers or a pointer pointing to an array of size 5?

Comment: That's array of pointers. Pointer to array `int (*a)[5];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an array of 5 pointers to `int`.

You might find the [right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) helpful.

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, use [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/).

Entering `int *a[5]`, the output is...

> declare a as array 5 of pointer to int

Thus, `a` is an array of 5 `int *`. :-)

Comment: "`C gibberish ↔ English`" - Love it! +1

Answer (score 0):

that's an array of pointers. that's because `int *` is a type, unlike the impression most people get that the type is `int` and the name is `*a` .